# Show that a derivative is positive

Tags: derivatives

Given $r_1, r_2 \in \Bbb R^+$, let the function $f : \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R^+$ be defined by $$f(x) = \frac{1- \text{exp}(-(r_1 +r_2)x)}{1-\text{exp}(-r_1x)}$$ I need to show that $f$ is increasing in $x$ for all $x > 0$.

---

I've tried obviously to differentiate, without success. Can someone help me? I basically get that this is increasing if and only if:

$\frac{1- \text{exp}(-(r_1 +r_2)\Lambda)}{1-\text{exp}(-r_2\Lambda)} > 1 + r_1/r_2$

I differentiate again the LHS and and I get that the LHS is increasing in $x$ iff (I did this to try to find some contradiction)

$\frac{1- \text{exp}(-(r_1 +r_2)\Lambda)}{1-\text{exp}(-r_1\Lambda)} > 1 + r_2/r_1$

And so on... What should I conclude!?

Edit: the domain and the codomain are $R_{+}$

Comment: I edited a bit.  Please edit the rest.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is right? Try $r_1=r_2=1$. Then $$\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-x}}=1+e^{-x}$$This function is decreasing

Comment: No, it's not. I was literally going crazy. I received the answer in the other question